# How to set context path of web application in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, servlets, contextpath

I have a project using Jakarta EE and I'm trying to set a contextual path, but I can't do it. When setting the context path in the web.xml, everything works the same as without it. If you try to get it through ServletContext.getContextPath(), then outputs an empty string.  I attach screenshots web.xml file, jsp file and project structure.[web config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0mfj.png),  [jsp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEu7R.png),  [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYKxf.png)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnaeb/index.html):

> A context root identifies a web application in a Java EE server. A context root must start with a forward slash (/) and end with a string.

Which means the root context path is determined by the application server when the web application is deployed. If you do not deploy a WAR file but rather try to run the project using the embed server(tomcat etc), you can not directly set the root context path of the application in the web.xml file. Rather set it in either `application.properties` or `application.yml` file like this

```
server.servlet.context-path=/my-app
```

When you are deploying a WAR file in servers like GlassFish or JBoss, you have to add server-specific files in the `WEB-INF` folder.

- For JBoss add `jboss-web.xml`
- For GlassFish add `sun-web.xml`

Then in the `jboss-web.xml` file add the following configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/my-app</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Now you can access API by appending context root at the beginning.